# Add inline function with IF/ELSE clause in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have table A. If I make a query with inline function

```
with function f(n number) return varchar2 as
   begin
    return 'const string';
   end;
select id, val, count, f(count) as value from A;
```

the result will be following:

```
    ID         VAL                       COUNT VALUE
    ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------------
     1         car                           4 const string
     2         building                     15 const string
```

But if I try to make the function more complicated

```
with function f(n number)
   return varchar2 as
   begin
    IF n < 5 THEN
            return 'small';
        ELSIF n < 50 THEN
            return 'normal';
        ELSE 
            return 'big';
        END IF;
    end;
select id, val, count, f(count) as value from A;
```

an error message appears:

```
with function f(n number)
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

What's the problem here? Do I use right syntax for the command?

Comment: May be the Missing `THEN` for your first `ELSIF`..

Comment: Yes, THEN should be there but original error is not disappeared

Comment: I know it sounds ridiculous can you try running the sql giving a new line after `WITH` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement is missing a `then` after the `elsif` condition clause, hence the missing keyword error pointing to function `f`. Also, after you fix this error you may get a `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` pointing to the last semi-colon. Interestingly, the ";" does not seem to work as a terminator to the SQL statement when the PL/SQL declaration is included in the WITH clause. If we attempt to use it on its own, SQL*Plus waits for more text to be entered. So you have to end it with a `/` on a new line. Even in the example in [SQL Reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_10002.htm#BABJFIDC) uses a combination of `;` and `/`. Here is my example I tested in PL/SQL Developer 11:

```
WITH
 FUNCTION f(n number) return varchar2 IS
   begin
     if n<5 then 
       return 'small';
     elsif (n>5 AND n<50) then
       return 'medium';
     else 
       return 'big';
      end if;     
   end;  
select f(25) from dual
/
```

Output:

```
F(25)
medium
```

EDIT: Also, change your `AS` to `IS` in your function definition.